# jQuery's draggable() and angular's ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have the following code.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in canvasElements" id="declareContainer">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Javascript (Angular)

```
(function(){

  //angular module
  var dataElements = angular.module('dataElements', ['angularTreeview','ngResource']);

  //test controller
  dataElements.controller('myController', function($scope,$resource){

    $scope.nodeClicked = function(node){
      alert(node.roleName);
    }

    $scope.canvasElements = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  });

})();
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$("#declareContainer").draggable({curosr: "move"});
```

The HTML that this generates on the page creates a div for each item in the array so you get something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in canvasElements" id="declareContainer" class="ng-scope ng-binding ui-draggable">
  item1
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in canvasElements" id="declareContainer" class="ng-scope ng-binding ui-draggable">
  item2
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in canvasElements" id="declareContainer" class="ng-scope ng-binding ui-draggable">
  item3
</div>
```

But only the first one is draggable. How would I make it so each individual div that gets generated can be draggable?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues:

1. IDs are unique.  Don't repeat an element with an id, just use the classes
2. You are running the jQuery selector before angular renders, so you are only selecting the initial DOM element, not the others.
3. You should do DOM manipulation within an angular directive via the `link` function

Answer (score 2):

What Matt say's is true, but there is a work-around you could use.
The problem is that your jQuery function runs before Angular is done manipulating the DOM.

The easiest way to fix that, is to inject the Angular $timeout function to place your code higher on the callstack.

HTML(Load angular in head):

```
<div ng-app="dataElements" ng-controller="myController">
   <div class="declareContainer" ng-repeat="item in canvasElements">
       {{item}}
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
  //angular module
  var dataElements = angular.module('dataElements', []);

  //test controller
  dataElements.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){

      $scope.canvasElements = [
          "item1", 
          "item2",
          "item3"
      ];

      $timeout(function(){ { //Move code up the callstack to tell Angular to watch this
          $(".declareContainer").draggable();
      });
  });
})();
```

I've set up a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Yellowface/erowksrx/) to see it work